# javascript throw statement inside jquery ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

So I am wondering if the following is legal, perhaps its not working due to a syntax error.?   Simple validation of four rules on a single search field.   Thanks for any help towards an elegant and enlightening solution!

```
 $(function() { 
    $('input.text').focus(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('noSubmitX');
        $('.enterX').removeClass('now').text( orig);
    });  //reset error status

    var orig = "Enter the title you want.";
    var msg1 = "Title must be between 3 and 63 characters.";
    var msg2 = "Title cannot begin or end with a hypen";
    var msg3 = "Title cannot contain a hyphen at character positions 3 and 4";

    $('form.xSearch').submit(function() {
        var theSearch = $('input.text').val();
        var xLong = $('input.text').val().length;
        var firstx = (theSearch[0]);
        var thirdx = (theSearch[2]);
        var fourthx = (theSearch[3]);
        var lastx = (theSearch[xLong - 1]);
        try {
            if (xLong < 2 || xLong > 62) {
                throw "msg1";
            }
            else if (firstx == "-") || (lastx == "-") {
                throw "msg2";
            }
            else if (thirdx == "-") && (fourthx == "-")

            {
                throw "msg3";
            }
        }
        catch (er) {
            if (er == 'msg1') {
                $('input.text').addClass('noSubmitX');
                $('.enterX').addClass('now').text('Title must be between 3 and 63 characters.');
            }
            if (er == 'msg2') {
                $('input.text').addClass('noSubmitX');
                $('.enterX').addClass('now').text('Title cannot begin or end with a hypen');
            }
            if (er == 'msg3') {
                $('input.text').addClass('noSubmitX');
                $('.enterX').addClass('now').text('Title cannot contain a hyphen at character positions 3 and 4');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What actually happens when you try to run it? You need to return false from your submit handler if you want to stop the submit going ahead.

Comment: If you read the question, it clearly says it doesn't run because of a syntax error.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - no, it says "perhaps its not working due to a syntax error?", and "not working" could mean almost anything, including running but giving the wrong result. (And I did point out what seemed to me to be the most likely issue.)

Comment: Why would you throw errors? seems very silly thing to do for form validation. Plus you have so much repeated code it is scary.

Comment: This is a scaled down version of my actual function.   Thanks for those of you that provided the constructive comments.  I would welcome any alternative function to accomplish the same thing without using validation plugin.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're running into trouble with your `if` statements. They need to be wrapped in parenthesis or wrapped like so:

```
if (xLong < 2 || xLong > 62) {
    throw "msg1";
}
else if (firstx == "-" || lastx == "-") {
    throw "msg2";
}
else if (thirdx == "-" && fourthx == "-") {
    throw "msg3";
}
```

Comment: +1.  Of course, the OP can have the interior parentheses if he wants too.  `else if ((firstx == "-") || (lastx == "-")) {`